# Run gulp task after NPM package install

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I've developed a small package that I'm serving from a github repo. It's basically a UI Library and it has only a SCSS file.

```
my-ui-library
-- src/styles.scss
```

I would like that after the installation the package run itself a gulp task that compiles the CSS, and move it to other location.

The desired output, after the gulp task is run, is something like this:

```
my-ui-library
-- src/styles.scss
-- styles.scss
```

I've included some scripts

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "gulp"
}
```

I can´t find the way to run gulp after the install of the package.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you just have to specify the gulp task you'd like to run in the postinstall script.

Comment: It is not possible to have a specific gulpfile for the package itself?

Comment: That should work. Calling just "gulp" in your postinstall script tells gulp to execute the default task defined in your gulpfile. What is the error you're seeing from your current setup?

Comment: It works in that way, without any problem, but I would like to have a specific gulpfile for the package, dont want to mix the main gulpfile with the package gulpfile.

Answer (score 1):

In your `postinstall` script you can use the [`--gulpfile` flag](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md#flags) for `gulp` to specify where your other gulp file to use is.

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "gulp --gulpfile <path-to-gulpfile>"
}
```

Comment: where I have to mention my gulp task which has been placed in my packages?

Comment: it is not working for me. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236303/run-gulp-task-after-npm-package-install-without-any-command

Comment: @kumaresan_sd This answer is 100% correct. The downvote was unwarranted,  you're experiencing a totally different problem related to your usage of gulp. This answer addresses **_this_ question** and not the one you linked.

Comment: i am also expecting the same scenario, after my package got install i want run some gulp task in post-install. How do you say my questino is different?